# Macro send notification when release date is not valid anymore

Tags: excel, notifications, macros, send, vba

Next is some macro which compare cell D with current date and if it is in past it send notification to email defined in cell L. The problem here is that the macro need to be run manually by pressing Alt+F8, so the question is how to make the macro automatically run when it noticed that updated cell D value is in past, so there is no need all the time to run the macro manually.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim RelDate As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim dateCell, dateCell1 As Date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each RelDate In Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
If RelDate = "" Then GoTo 1
dateCell = RelDate.Value
dateCell1 = Cells(RelDate.Row, "C").Value

If dateCell < Date Then ' this if cell value is smalle than today then   it will send notification
      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Cells(RelDate.Row, "L").Value
            .Subject = "Release Date Changed"         ' Change your massage subject here
            'Change body of the massage here
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(RelDate.Row, "E").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "The release date of " & Cells(RelDate.Row, "A").Value & _
                    " is changed to " & dateCell _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                    "Your Name"
            .send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    ' Cells(RelDate.Row, "C").Value = dateCell
   ' RelDate.ClearContents
   1:  Next RelDate
   cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: What about the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in worksheet_change event. It will compare the date in all the changed cells in column "D" and if condition is true, it will call the sendmail procedure. Please adjust your sendmail code accordingly.
This code also works if you copy paste multiple rows of data.
Hope that help!. :-)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim to_email As String
Dim subject As String
Dim body As String
For Each cell In Target.Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    If cell.Column = 4 And cell < Date Then
        On Error GoTo errhandler
        to_email = ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value
        subject = "Release Date Changed"
        body = "Dear " & ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "The release date of " & ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & _
                " is changed to " & ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 4) _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                "Your Name"
        sendmail to_email, subject, body
    End If
Next cell

Exit Sub

errhandler:
Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description

End Sub



Sub sendmail(to_email As String, subject As String, body As String)
```

> adjust your code accordingly

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Imran a lot, but could you explain a little bit more about what you mean by adjusting sendmail code?I tried your code as you wrote above but nothing happen :(